# Linq version of SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: asp.net, linq, concurrency

I'm getting a `ChangeConflictException` in my web application when the code updates a certain row within a certain table. The best I can tell it seems as though two users are completing the transaction at the same exact time and optimistic concurrency only affect the `SubmitChanges()` method instead of doing the lock when the row is selected.

So in other words I have a transaction like this:

```
Dim query = From row in Table _
            Where row.ID = <blah> _
            Select row
Dim result = query.Single()
result.COLUMN = 2
dataContext.SubmitChanges()
```

The built-in optimistic concurrency locks the record when `SubmitChanges()` is called but if the record is changed after `Single()` and before `SubmitChanges()` then an error is thrown.

...at least that's my theory...

Does anyone know of a way to start the lock at the `Single()` call instead of just at `SubmitChanges()`?

Comment: From how I understand it, it seems as though SubmitChanges() has  built-in transaction handling. So there might be a solution that could just change the way that built-in transaction is handled. For example: DataContext.ExecuteCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
SERIALIZABLE") or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to wrap your transaction in a try/catch block, and deal with the exception that is thrown.  Linq to SQL provides plenty of information to allow you to deal with the exception in an intelligent manner.  See http://elsharpo.blogspot.com/2008/04/handling-concurrency-conflicts-in-linq.html

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do transactions with Linq to SQL - but I haven't got there yet.

I agree it may also be better to deal with the problem of resolving the concurrency issue (prompt the user) than to use a transaction however, a couple of links that may help:

[LINQ to SQLTransactions (LINQ to SQL) (Microsoft)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386995.aspx)

and a short video:

http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/nuggets/nugget/206/Transactions-in-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that could possibly work is to use DataContext.ExecuteCommand and send your own update statement.